# detail view controller not passing values back to master controller

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I have the following statement that populates a table from a json feed. After selecting a row from the table it passes back to the original controller for it to query an api again to populate some fields.

The problem is that the value being passed back does not relate to the cell that has been selected.

here si my code.

in the detail view controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *addressdict = [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *address = [addressdict objectForKey:@"StreetAddress"];
    idnumber = [addressdict objectForKey:@"Id"];
    cell.textLabel.text = address;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = idnumber;
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sendAddress"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SignUpViewController *controller = (SignUpViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        controller->idnumber = idnumber;
    }
}
```

In my master view controller i do this

```
NSLog(@"The Address ID is: %@",idnumber);
```

but the value is it returning is not correct.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to pass data to the next UIViewController or pass data back to the previous UIViewController? If you are trying to pass data back to the previous UIViewController, you should use delegation.

Comment: I am trying to pass back to the previous UIViewController, How would i use delegation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use delegation to pass data back to the previous UIViewController.

E.g.

**UIViewControllerB.h**

```
// Declare a protocol that conforms to NSObject
@protocol UIViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>

// @required is the default, but means that the delegate must implement the following methods
@required
- (void)viewController:(UIViewController)aViewController didSelectIDNumber:(NSNumber *)anIDNumber;

@end
```

**UIViewControllerB.m**

```
@interface UIViewControllerB : NSObject

// Keep a reference to the delegate so we can call the above methods
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UIViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;

@end


@implementation UIViewControllerB

 - (NSNumber *)idNumberAtIndex:(int)anIndex
 {
    NSNumber *idNumber = nil;

    if (jsonData && anIndex <= [jsonData count])
    {
        NSDictionary *addressDictionary = jsonData[anIndex];

        idNumber = addressDictionary[@"Id"];
    }
    return idNumber;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // When a row is selected let the delegate know the idNumber
     [self.delegate viewController:self didSelectIDNumber:[self idNumberAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

@end
```

**UIViewControllerA.m**

```
// Make UIViewControllerA conform the the UIViewControllerBDelegate
@implementation UIViewControllerA <UIViewControllerBDelegate>

// Implement the required UIViewControllerB Delegate Method
- (void)viewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController didSelectIDNumber:(NSNumber *)anIDNumber
{
    // do something with the id number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely wrong, you are trying to set the value for `idnumber` in function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your case it will have the last value the tableview displays.

You should try to get `idnumber` in tableview method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: hi, i added the following but now i just a null value. -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *addressdict = [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    idnumber = [addressdict objectForKey:@"Id"];

}